# plugin ":mail:1.0.7" has syntax error on execution

Tags: email, grails

```
mail {
    host = "smtp.1und1.de"
    port = 465
    username = "pt8100853-1"
    password = "xxxxxxxx"
    props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",                      
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
}
```

is the contents of config groovy. My controller contains

```
sendMail {
        to "gaby@strotmann.org"
        subject "Hello Fred"
        body 'How are you?'
      }
```

After activating sendMail I get:

```
Error 2015-02-25 21:19:25,883 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR      errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MailSendException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Partner/kommunikation/eMail
Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments    
;
 nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in   parameters or arguments
. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException:  501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments
;
  nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in   parameters or arguments
    Line | Method
->>  131 | sendMessage in grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   - 
|     55 | sendMail    in grails.plugin.mail.MailService
|     59 | sendMail .  in     ''
|    165 | doCall      in MailGrailsPlugin$_configureSendMail_closure6
|     37 | eMail . . . in   org.strotmann.partner.KommunikationController
|    198 | doFilter    in   grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter .  in   grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . in  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run         in java.lang.Thread
```

I'm somewhat confused to get a syntax error, as I copied the original code directly from the plugin documentation.

How can I escape that problem?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: GGTS-3.6.1 which comes with grails 2.4.3

Comment: See what's strange is the error isn't matching what your code is trying to do. Typically this error message is: 501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments

Error Description: Means that the remote server is sending incorrect commands through to the server. This occurs when the msg contains a line that is too long and as such cannot be read by the SMTP service.

Error Resolution: Check the SMTP debug logs in this situation as there should be more information on what is occurring. If the logs do not help then check how the message is being sent to see if you can find anything that is abnormal.

Comment: Where can I find the SMTP debug logs ?

Comment: Those typically exist on the target SMTP server. You could also set the `com.sun.mail.smtp` package to `trace` and see if you can find any further information on your side.

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for your efforts so far, but checking logs, that I have no accest to is impossible for me. Also a trace of a package is something I've never done and I never will do. I changed to apache commons-email instead, which I made running with some mouseclicks this afternoon.

Comment: Did you get it managed to bring it to work? Because I'm getting the same errror if I try to configure 1und1 smtp on a jenkins server. Seems like this is a common 1und1 problem.